# Java: Foreach loop not working as expected on int array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, foreach

I've got a pretty simple loop:

```
int[] positions = {1, 0, 0}

//print content of positions

for (int i : positions)
{
    if (i <= 0) i = -1;
}

//print content of positions
```

Now, what I would expect to get is:

```
array: 1, 0, 0
array: 1, -1, -1
```

but instead I get

```
array: 1, 0, 0
array: 1, 0, 0
```

Just... why?

Kind regards,
jellyfish

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because "`i`" is a copy of an array element and not a reference to it :)
You modify a local variable, not an array's element

this code is equivalent to

```
for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {

int i = array[index];
...
}
```

Comment: it took me a long time to find this answer... i have an array and was instantiating objects inside foreach, and accessing them later with index, and i got null pointer exception. so for and foreach are NOT the same...

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. If you write

```
int i = positions[0];
```

Then you copy `positions[0]` by value, not by reference. You cannot modify the original value in `positions[0]` from `i`. The same applies to assigning `i` within a foreach loop.

The solution is without a foreach loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++)
{
    if (positions[i] <= 0) positions[i] = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens behind the scenes if we use the enhanced for loop with arrays:

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
for($i = 0; $i<array.length; $i++) {
  int i = array[$i];
  // your statements
  if (i <= 0) i = -1;
}
```

`$i` is just a placeholder for an unnamed internal loop variable. See what happens: you assign a new value to `i` but `i` is loaded with the next array item in the next iteration.

So, practically spoken, we can't use the variable declared in the enhanced for loop to modify the underlying array.

<sup>Reference: JLS 3.0, 14.14.2</sup>